# Can't Get Post Data Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, rest, post

I tried to make rest API for my android app using codeigniter, first I don't have trouble using get method, all parameter data can be sent. But when it came to post method, the rest API can't get the header. any solution will be great.

thanks

here is my url using get method:

```
http://10.34.1.122/a-kit-android/api/cont_a_kit/start_mesin_operasi?id_mesin=10&operasi=1
```

here is my url using post method:

```
http://10.34.1.122/a-kit-android/api/cont_a_kit/start_mesin_operasi
```

> header : id_mesin = 10, operasi=1

here is my controller:

```
function start_mesin_operasi()
    {
        $idMesin = $this->input->post("id_mesin");

        $data = array(      
                  'operasi' => $this->input->post("operasi"),                 
                 );

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo 'id mesin: '.$idMesin;
        echo json_encode($this->mod_a_kit->start_mesin($idMesin, $data));
    }
```

and here is my model:

```
function start_mesin($id, $data)
        {   $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where('id_mesin', $id);
            $this->db->update('m_mesin', $data);            

            if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
                $response['status'] = 1;
                $response['message'] = "Mesin Telah Dihidupkan";
            }
            else{
                $response['status'] = 0;
                $response['message'] = "Start Mesin Gagal";             
            }

            return $response;
        }
```

Comment: What version of codeIgniter you using? Because I see your ip address in url you need to set your base_url in config.php if your using CI3 and above.

Comment: it was silly of me, I forget to create serverRequest object after declare a variable, so the app try to access to object which never made. thanks for your answer anyway.